# Preload images and insert into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, image-preloader

Hi I have a question about preloading images either in JS or jQuery. What I have is one image which I basically want to be repeated 16 times in a

```
<li>image here</li>
```

structure. I started out by basically inserting it into the list as is like this.

```
<ul>
   <li>image</li>
   <li>image</li>
   <li>image</li>
</ul>
```

16 times in my HTML. Works but not very pretty nor efficient. If I want to preload the image in my js and then insert into my HTML list. I have found some different ways of doing it [here](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript/).

Here they are cached but then I need to put them in the li. Any good suggestions?! Both JS and jQuery examples are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  $("li").prepend( this );
};
img.src = 'http://placehold.it/40x40/cf5';
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as a charm although I still keep all the li's in the DOM. It would be cool though to see this done in a prototyping way of doing it. I marked your answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Tim - I did not understand your comment well, but to insert the images right where you want, you need to be more specific about the selector, I used `.prependTo('li')` but you can do something like: `.prependTo('#myUList li')` . In that case you'll need: `<ul id="myUList">` Thx and happy coding

Comment: I keep seeing `load` called after `src` is set. This is a mistake. Always define your `load` callback *before* you set the `img`'s `src`.

Comment: @ChaseMoskal I don't understand your comment, can you clarify?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Some browsers may fire the `load` event at the exact moment you set the `src` attribute -- and since your `load` handler isn't bound yet -- you could miss it. It's best to ensure that your `load` event is *always* bound before it could possibly fire. Off the top of my head, if I recall correctly, Internet Explorer had an issue with this, where the load events for cached images fired immediately when the `src` is set -- load handlers chained afterwards were too late. I see many individuals appending '?4134timestamp312' to their `img` `src`s to combat this- no good- ruins caching.

Comment: This has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8.  It's also inconsistent across browsers and shouldn't be used.  https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

After you cache your image (using the code http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript/) you simple run a javascript loop:

```
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
  $('ul#your_ul_id').append('<li><img src="your_image_url"/></li>');
}
```

Comment: Ok, so then I would run the loop after this line `cache.push(cacheImage);` and then in my HTML remove al the `<li>` so only the ul remains?! Or did I misunderstand you? Thanks.

Comment: Also, give your <ul> an id. In the code, I assume the id is "your_ul_id". Change it accordingly.

Comment: Yes I noticed:) Although I did not get it to behave the way I wanted. This image path `var imgSrc = 'path/to/image.jpg';` just outputted a string into the DOM. Fully possible I missed something though.

Answer (score 0):

I would trigger a .load() event for the original image and only then clone the DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var img = $('<img id="yourImg">'); 
img.load(function() {
// repeat this step ad libitum
$(this).clone().appendTo(whatever)
});
img.attr('src', yourURL);
img.appendTo(whatever2);
});
```