# How to add multiple images to the DOM all at once with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, append

I am creating a creating `img` elements for multiple images received from an array with `each` loop, but I'd like to insert all of them to the DOM at once, but they are being added one at a time, in other words, I want to wait until all of the elements are created before they are shown on the DOM.

I've created this logic hoping that I could achieve what I want.

```js
    const projectData = [
      {coverImg: '../someImg-1.png},
      {coverImg: '../someImg-2.png},
      {coverImg: '../someImg-3.png},
      {coverImg: '../someImg-4.png},
   ]



$(function() {
  let imagesArr = []

  const projects_container = $('<div></div>')
  projects_container.addClass('projects_container')

  $.each(projectData, (index, value) => {
    const card_block_El = $('<div></div>')
    card_block_El.appendTo(projects_container)

    const card_img_div_El = $('<div></div>')
    const card_img_El = $('<img>')
    card_img_El.attr('src', value.coverImg)
    card_img_El.appendTo(card_img_div_El)

    card_img_div_El.appendTo(card_block_El)

    imagesArr.push(card_block_El)
  })

  if (imagesArr.length >= projetosData.length) {
    projects_container.appendTo('#projects')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="projects"></div>
```

What I thought is, well, the elements will be created and appended to `projects_container` one at a time within the loop, but after the loop, since all images will already be appended to its container (what is verified by the conditional), when I append the container to `projects`, they will be loaded all at once, but that's not what is happening, the images are being inserted to the DOM one at a time, even if they are already created. I just started learning JQuery and I believe I didn't get it right.

How could I achieve this?

P.S. I am fetching the images from Firebase Firestore to `projectData` file and importing it to this script.

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and replace the import with example data

Comment: It looks like your code should already do what you want. What is it that makes you think the elements are being inserted to the DOM one at a time?

Comment: @Ouroborus well, I can see it. When I run the live demo the images are like: first img... second img... third img... and so on. They are not inserted at once, as a pack of imgs.

Comment: The images are loaded one at a time, perhaps that is what you are seeing. If you want all of the images to show up at once, preload them, and only insert the HTML for them once all of the images have completed loading.

Comment: The appearance of one-by-one loading isn't due to your code, it's due to either your browser or a slow connection. For example, with a slow connection and large files, it will appear as though the images are loading one by one even though the elements were added to the document simultaneously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preload images and insert into DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367338/preload-images-and-insert-into-dom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this

- I hide the container
- I preload and append the HTML in one go
- When the last image has loaded I show the container

```js
const projectData = [
{ coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image1' }, 
{ coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image2' }, 
{ coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image3' }, 
{ coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image4' }, 
{ coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image5' }, 
{ coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image6' }, 
{ coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image7' }, 
{ coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image8' } 
]

$(function() {
  const $projects_container = $("#projects");
  let counter = 0
  $projects_container.addClass('projects_container')
  $projects_container.html(projectData.map((value, i) => {    
    let img = new Image;
    $(img).on("load",() => {
      counter++;
      if (counter===projectData.length) {
        $('#projects').fadeIn("slow")
      }  
    })
    img.src=value.coverImg;
    const html = `<div class="card_block">
           <div class="card_img_div_El">Image ${i+1}<br/>
             <img class="card_img_El" src="${img.src}"/>
           </div>
         </div>`;
    return html
  }).join(''));
  const $images = $("#projects").find('.card_img_El');
  
})
```

```css
#projects { display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projects"></div>
```

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: While I agree that this is a better approach, this doesn't actually answer OP's question. They're already using a container element, inserting everything into that container, and then inserting that container into the document. While slower, it produces the same effect. OP's question is: Why does it seem like the elements are being inserted directly into the doc one by one?

Comment: If you add code to preload the images (e.g., `new Image()`), this would answer the question. as it is, it's the same code, streamlined.

Comment: I'm trying to apply that, but I didn't really get it. Specially at two points, I am trying to append `projects_container` to `#projects` and not the other way around, besides that I didn't get what I should do with `$images`, would that be the conditional?

Comment: @Ouroborus  so you're saying that with my code I should get the outcome I want. Is that correct?

Comment: @Berg_Durden In the technical sense, yes. If, with regards to presentation, you want the user to see a delay and then everything pop up at once, simultaneously, you'll need to preload the images. Then, when they're all loaded and ready to go, populate the DOM. How to preload is thoroughly discussed elsewhere on stackoverflow so asking in this question would make it a duplicate. One possibility is linked in the comments on your question.

Comment: @Berg_Durden I am sorry, I was interrupted. I have fixed the typos and am preloading the images

Comment: @HereticMonkey You mean something like above, right?

Comment: Sure, but I think the duplicate I found already covers this...

Comment: Hmm, it is not a very elegant script and it is downvoted. I think OP would have a harder time implementing the link you gave than my code above

Answer (score 1):

You could wait until every image is loaded,I would do this with settimeout.

```js
const projectData = [
    { coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image1' },
    { coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image2' },
    { coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image3' },
    { coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image4' },
    { coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image5' },
    { coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image6' },
    { coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image7' },
    { coverImg: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=image8' }
];


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    
    const projects_container = document.createElement("div");
    projects_container.classList.add('projects_container');
    for(i=0;i<projectData.length;i++)
    {
        const card_block_El   = document.createElement("div");
        const card_img_div_El = document.createElement("div");
        const card_img_El     = document.createElement("img");
        card_img_El.src       = projectData[i].coverImg;

        card_img_div_El.appendChild(card_img_El);
        card_block_El.appendChild(card_img_div_El);
        projects_container.appendChild(card_block_El);
    }


   document.getElementById("projects").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("projects").appendChild(projects_container)  ;


    var CheckImages=function () {
        var loadedimages=0;
        var images=document.getElementById("projects").getElementsByTagName("img");
        for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            if(images[i].complete && images[i].naturalHeight !== 0){
                loadedimages++;
            }

        }
        if(images.length ==loadedimages)
        {
            document.getElementById("projects").style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout(CheckImages, 1000);
        }
    }
    CheckImages();
  });
```

```html
<div id="projects"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you are right in this case it can be confusing, I personally find it not bad to have an example for the solution wihout any use of library, that works regardless what some people use in their project, and maybe struggling with this, I think too that you answer is better, I even upvoted it : ) .